# How to create a unique lowercase functional index using SQLAlchemy on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

This is the SQL I want to generate:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_lower_email_key ON users (LOWER(email));
```

From the SQLAlchemy [Index documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/constraints.html#indexes) I would expect this to work:

```
Index('users_lower_email_key', func.lower(users.c.email), unique=True)
```

But after I call `metadata.create(engine)` the table is created but this index is not. I've tried:

```
from conf import dsn, DEBUG

engine = create_engine(dsn.engine_info())

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine

users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('email', String),
    Column('first_name', String, nullable=False),
    Column('last_name', String, nullable=False),
    )

Index('users_lower_email_key', func.lower(users.c.email), unique=True)

metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Viewing the table definition in PostgreSQL I see that this index was not created.

```
\d users
                                   Table "public.users"
   Column   |       Type        |                        Modifiers
------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 user_id    | integer           | not null default nextval('users_user_id_seq'::regclass)
 email      | character varying |
 first_name | character varying | not null
 last_name  | character varying | not null
Indexes:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (user_id)
```

How can I create my lower, unique index?

Comment: I am also curious about this.

Comment: Why are you trying to take the lowercase of an `INTEGER` column.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I was about to ask the same thing because that does not work and Postgres with throw an error. However, if you use a `String` type, then the example works perfectly and without a hassle.

Comment: My mistake; I didn't notice that my example was trying to lowercase an Integer. I've updated the example to be my actual table, where the issue also occurs.

Comment: can you show *all* of your code?  Also, what version of SQLAlchemy are you using?  What version of PostgreSQL?  As mentioned in my answer, I have had no trouble creating the index using your code.

Comment: After squinting at your code a bit, I notice you're saying `metadata.create(engine)`, but `sqlalchemy.MetaData` does not have a `create()` method.  On the other hand, `sqlalchemy.Table` does.  When you call create on individual items like this, *only* the described objects are created.   Please check your code and verify that you are actually using `MetaData.create_all()`

Comment: I'm calling `metadata.create_all(engine)` (my example is again, incorrect; I should be more precise with my example code). I'm running PostgreSQL 9.1.6 and SQLAlchemy 0.8.0b2. I updated my question to include my complete example code (sans SQLA imports).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you want to index an integer column in lower case;  The problem is that the generated sql does not typecheck:

```
LINE 1: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX banana123 ON mytable (lower(col5))
                                                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX banana123 ON mytable (lower(col5))' {}
```

On the other hand, if you use an actual string type:

```
Column('col5string', String),
...
Index('banana123', func.lower(mytable.c.col5string), unique=True)
```

The index is created as expected.   If, for some very strange reason, you are insistent about this absurd index, you just need to fix the types:

```
Index('lowercasedigits', func.lower(cast(mytable.c.col5, String)), unique=True)
```

Which produces perfectly nice:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX lowercasedigits ON mytable (lower(CAST(col5 AS VARCHAR)))
```

Comment: I didn't realize that my example was trying to lowercase an integer. I updated my example to use a string, where the index also fails to be created.